# for loop ( loop variable name)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have some variables a1 to a14 and another set of variables q1 to q14 , and I am trying to do a for loop like this

```
for(var i:uint = 1; i < 15; i++)
{ 
 if (this("a"+i).x== this("q"+i).x )
{points= points+1 }
else
{
this("q"+i.visible=false;
// shows the good answer 
 }
}
```

Please help :)

Comment: What do you think about this line... this("q"+i.visible=false;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties of objects can be accessed via square brackets, similar to indexes in an array.
Each property name (the variable name) is actually a variable key.
It is also recommended to CHECK that the object actually HAS the property, using the Object.hasOwnProptery(propertyName:String) method.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001424.html

Example:

```
 for(var i:uint = 1; i < 15; i++){ 
    if (this["a"+i].x== this["q"+i].x ){
        points= points+1;
    }
    else{
        this["q"+i].visible=false;
        // shows the good answer 
    }
}
```

I have not checked, but it may be wise to use Number instead of uint and toString to retrieve it's string value when creating the variable name

Comment: `uint` is fine (actually, preferable) in this case.